# SQLException no such column on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm getting an entry in my database like this :

`participant = Participant.where(id_request: params[:id_request], user_id: params[:user_id]).first`

This will get the actual `Participant` because I logged it underneath, this is what that logs :

`#<Participant id_request: "2", user_id: "titivermeesch@gmail.com">`

So that is ok because it corresponds to the parameters that are giving from my frontend.

Now the thing is, I'm doing this to destroy that : 
`participant.destroy`

Once this is executed I will get this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: participants.: DELETE FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."" IS NULL):

app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:35:in `destroy'
```

So why do I get this? `participant` isn't null and the parameters are not null too.

`Participant` tabel:

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
    validates :id_request, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :id_request}
end
```

I'm using this to link `Request` and `User`

Comment: This looks like you are doing something really strange with the primary key in your model. Please include the model.

Comment: There is no primary key here, this is to link to tables together, I added the `Participant` table

Comment: You need a primary key for ActiveRecord to actually work properly. You could possibly get around it with `Participant.where(conditions).delete_all` but this smacks of bad design.

Comment: How can I do this then? There are a lot of cases where the database don't have id's.

Comment: "How can I do this then?" - I have already explained that you don't. Add primary keys to the tables you want to use for ActiveRecord models. It just does not work otherwise. You can have "headless" assocations with `has_and_belongs_to_many` (association with no model), but having a model without a PK is just stupid since there is no effective way to identify it, and AR does not support compound PKs.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll do it like that. You can post this as an answer if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and resolved it. I had a dependent: :destroy association, and when trying to destroy that object, the destroy action was looking for the associated objects to destroy.

However, I had already deleted them, leaving un-associated IDs in the original object that were throwing errors of No such column.